# ajax post redirect after form submit and put serialized data to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

In index.asp i include login.asp file

> Content of index.asp

```
<div class="wrapper pop-up" id="wrapper.pop-up" style="display:none">
<!--#include file="Login.asp"-->
</div>
<div class="log_in">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
</div>
```

Then i have event when Login link on click

```
$(".log_in a").on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("wrapper.pop-up").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("authorizeID").style.display = "block";
});
```

Login.asp file content

```
<!-- #include file = "includes\functions\X-Login.asp" -->

<%
response.write(Session("UserID"))
    If Request.Form("POST_Action") = "LoginUser" Then
        Dim objCredentialsParms
        Set objCredentialsParms = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        objCredentialsParms.Add "EMailAddress", Request.Form("EMailAddress")
        objCredentialsParms.Add "PassWord", Request.Form("PassWord")
        Call LoginUser(objCredentialsParms)
        objCredentialsParms.RemoveAll()
        Set objCredentialsParms = Nothing
        Response.End()
    End If

%>
<script>
 $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
   // e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/Login.asp',
        type:'POST',
        data:$('#contactForm').serialize(),

    });
});
</script>
<div class="authorize" id="authorizeID" style="display:none">

    <a href="#" id="authorize-closeBut" class="authorize-close">
        <img src="img/icons/cross.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="authorize-caption">
        <span>AUTH
    </div>

    <form  id="contactForm" name="frmLogin" class="enter">
    <input type="hidden" name="POST_Action" value="LoginUser" >
    <%
    If Session("Error") <> "" Then
        Response.Write("<tr>" & vbCrLf & "<td style=""color: #ff0000;font-weight: bold;"">Error(s):</td>" & vbCrLf & "<td>" & Session("Error") & "</td>" & vbCrLf & "</tr>")
        Session.Contents.Remove("Error")
    End If
    %>
        <input name="EMailAddress" type="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
        <input name="PassWord" type="password" placeholder="ПАРОЛЬ">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

So when i click on Login link i got popup Login window
After form submit if user exist i got a blank page, if user not exist i got redirect to index.asp and data serialized in post request is added to url

File X-Login.asp has no redirects and only set session("Error") on each user state ( exist, not, blocked)

1. So i need to show in opened popup Session("Error") messeges whithout
   closing this popup
2. And i need not to add serialized data to url
3. Also i confirmed how to send data not in plain text for security reason
   whithout Https